# Typescript cloud function to aggregate firestore field value

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a document where i have two fields;

1. category
2. duration in micromilliseconds

Category could have multiple values like category1, category2 etc.

I want to calculate sum of duration of all the documents where category == category1. Please help with the query.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'


admin.initializeApp()

export const updateCharts = 
functions.firestore.document('users/{UserId}/count/{uid}')
.onWrite(async(change, _) => await updateStats(change))

async function updateStats (change: 
functions.Change<functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>){
const chartRating = change.after.ref.parent

let title = (await chartRating.where('Title', '==', 'Game').get()).size;
//duration

const restaurantRef = chartRating.parent!

console.log('{restaurantRef.path} now has ${Title}')
await restaurantRef.update({
Title: Title,

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fetch all the documents using a query it's you can use `reduce()` to find total duration:

```js
let title = await chartRating.where('Title', '==', 'Game').get();

const totalDuration = title.docs.reduce((a, b) => a + b.data()["duration"], 0)
// Adds 'duration' field of all documents
```

A cheaper alternative would be to read previous total from `restaurantRef`, subtracting old value of that's document's duration and adding the updated value. This will cost only 1 read and 1 write operation whereas reading all documents will cost N reads where N is number of documents matched.

Comment: I have already added a duration field in my documents. So each document is having a duration field with value. I want to get total of all duration for a specific category.